# How to Handle Undefined Values in TypeScript with RenderIf Component Similar to JS && Check

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have recently moved over to typescript and have been enjoying the benefits it has provided. I was trying to move over a pattern I used in React with javascript that I liked of a RenderIf component that checked whether it should show the content below or return null. The following code does work in typescript when not passing a potentially undefined value. I am stumped on how to help the typescript compiler realize that we already did the && check to validate that the value exists if the value can be undefined. Any typescript masters out there who know how I might fix this?

RenderIf Component

```
type RenderIfProps = {
  condition: boolean;
};

export const RenderIf: React.FC<RenderIfProps> = (props) => {
  const { condition = false, children } = props;
  const isConditionMetAndHasChildren = condition === true && !!children;

  if (isConditionMetAndHasChildren) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  }
  return null;
};
```

Example of typescript not being happy with RenderIf

```
const someComponent = (props: { someValue?: string }) => {
  return (
    <RenderIf condition={!!props?.someValue}>
      <ComponentA definedValue={props.someValue} />
    </RenderIf>
  )
}
```

Example of typescript being happy with &&

```
const someComponent = (props: { someValue?: string }) => {
  return (
    !!props?.someValue && <ComponentA definedValue={props.someValue} />
  )
}
```

---

Edit: This is the error message

`TS18049:  props  is possibly  null  or  undefined`

Comment: Please make sure you use .tsx instead of .ts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JasonMing. I am using tsx and that still is not solving the problem, unfortunately.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Please update the type RenderIfProps.
type RenderIfProps = {
  condition: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

Comment: Can you also provide exact TypeScript error along your code?

Comment: @JasonMing I believe that is taken care of via the FC. Either way that still is not a solution to the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela just updated with the TS Error

Comment: I see, so TypeScript will not know that your RenderIf valdiated your props and it should be OK within the children part, that's why second work as you assure it is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why doesn't it work? Because that's not how TypeScript works.

---

The `props.someValue` typing will always be the same on the same scope. In this case, the `RenderIf` and `ComponentA` functional components are in the same scope.

```
function SomeComponent(props: { someValue?: string }) {
  return (
    <RenderIf condition={!!props?.someValue}>
      <ComponentA definedValue={props.someValue} />
    </RenderIf>
  );
}
```

That's why `definedValue` props on `ComponentA` get this error: `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

---

#### Solution 1 - Children Structure

To make it work, we need to define the typescript scope of the functional component. If you want to keep the children-like structure like your example, I can share a solution to this.

##### 1. We need to adjust the `RenderIf` component:

```
type RenderIfProps = {
  definedValue?: string;
  children(definedValue: string): ReactElement;
};
function RenderIf(props: PropsWithChildren<RenderIfProps>) {
  const { definedValue, children } = props;

  if (!definedValue || !children) {
    return null;
  }

  return children(definedValue);
}
```

I adjusted the `RenderIf` functional component to:

- Accept `definedValue` string | undefined (not the boolean state)
- Re-define the `children` props from accepting a component to a function, this way I can change the scope of the typescript into the typing that I want.

##### 2. We need to adjust `SomeComponent` when calling `RenderIf`

```
function SomeComponent(props: { someValue?: string }) {
  return (
    <RenderIf definedValue={props?.someValue}>
      {(value) => <ComponentA definedValue={value} />}
    </RenderIf>
  );
}
```

I change how I call the children inside the `RenderIf` component. Instead of directly adding a component, I add a function, in which the parameter is a `string` type, not `string | undefined` like before. This is what I previously called changing the scope of the typing.

CodeSandbox example: [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-typescript-forked-739wqm?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A43%2C1)

---

I put the most similar solution to your example. Depending on the use case, this solution might not be the best. And since there are a lot of ways to achieve what you want, I put the "Solution 1" above.

Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Type narrowing like this sadly isn't possible, but there are some alternative solutions.

I think that most idiomatic is simply using `&&` or ternary:

```
const SomeComponent = (props: { someValue?: string }) => {
  return props.someValue ? (
    <ComponentA definedValue={props.someValue} />
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
};
```

For more complicated expressions (like using a switch statement deep inside some component) I reach out to IIFE-s, but it's a better practice to move complicated logic out of the component into the hook anyway, so try not to use this:

```
const SomeComponent = (props: { someValue?: string }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {(() => {
        if (props.someValue && props.someValue.length > 12) {
          return <div className="long">{props.someValue}</div>;
        } else if (props.someValue) {
          return <div>{props.someValue}</div>;
        } else {
          return "";
        }
      })()}
    </>
  );
};
```

You can get quite close to your `RenderIf` if you limit yourself to existence conditions and pass to it component wrapped as a function - so typescript can do type inference:

```
function RenderIf<T>({
  component,
  props,
}: {
  component: (props: T) => JSX.Element;
  props: T | null | undefined;
}) {
  if (props !== null && props !== undefined) {
    return component(props);
  } else {
    return <></>;
  }
}

const someComponent = (props: { someValue?: string }) => {
  return (
    <RenderIf
      component={(someValue) => <ComponentA definedValue={someValue} />}
      props={props.someValue}
    />
  );
};
```

Alternatively if you limit the RenderIf to checking if all props are present, you can shorten it even more using a custom type predicate:

```
function isFull<T extends {}>(props: Partial<T>): props is T {
  for (const key in props) {
    if (props[key] === undefined) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function RenderIfAllProps<T extends {}>({
  component,
  props,
}: {
  component: (props: T) => JSX.Element;
  props: Partial<T> | null | undefined;
}) {
  if (props !== null && props !== undefined && isFull(props)) {
    return component(props);
  } else {
    return <></>;
  }
}

const SomeComponent = (props: { someValue?: string }) => {
  return (
    <RenderIfAllProps
      component={ComponentA}
      props={{ definedValue: props.someValue }}
    />
  );
};
```

On the risk of repeating myself let me emphasize again that out of these `&&` and ternary statement are by far the simplest and thus probably best.